# Loading .ejs file failed using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have searched many articles and posts asked in different sites, but I didn't find any proper answer. I'm using `ejs` in my project to render book details in my page.

> My project structure looks like:
>
> - asset > ...
> - server > server.js
> - views > main > bookShow.ejs

I've used the `ejs` library as the following piece of code in `server.js`:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

and I've returned the `bookShow.ejs` in GET request as:

```
router.get('/bookShow/:isPageNoSorted/:page', (req, res) => {
    var isPageNoSorted = req.params.isPageNoSorted || false;
    var page = req.params.page || 1;
    var perPage = 5;
    if (isPageNoSorted == "true") {
        bookModel.find({
                isDeleted: false
            }).sort('-pageCount')
            .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
            .limit(perPage)
            .exec((err, data) => {
                if (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        bookModel.find({
                            isDeleted: false
                        }).count().exec((err, count) => {
                            res.render(
                                'main/bookShow', {
                                    books: data,
                                    pageCount: count,
                                    currentPage: page
                                }
                            );
                        })
                    } 
                }
            })
    } 
});
```

but nothing is shown in the browser. It seems to be OK and I have seen another sample that works in another [site](https://evdokimovm.github.io/javascript/nodejs/mongodb/pagination/expressjs/ejs/bootstrap/2017/08/20/create-pagination-with-nodejs-mongodb-express-and-ejs-step-by-step-from-scratch.html#). Is there any possible way that put my files in arbitrary directory using express middleware? For example my project structure is like:

> assets > views > bookShow.ejs

Comment: try moving the ejs to the relative path in your 'res.render() '  stmt.... ie ./bookshow/main/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code to use it:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/your-path '))
```